# new operator in a function C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to define the size of *arr and allocate memory for it inside the function init_array. But it leads to `segmentation fault`. What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve this result?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int init_array(int* arr)
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Number of elements? ";
    cin>>n;
    arr = new int[n];
    for(int j=0; j!= n; j++)
        arr[j] = j*j;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int *arr=nullptr;
    int n;
    n = init_array(arr);
    for(int i=0; i!=n; i++)
        cout<<*(arr+i);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: do you really have to manipulate memory? There are safer ways to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: @Red.Wave - In my project arr is a huge object. So the fewer times I copy it or move it, the better it is. Also, I want to call the function init_array() a few times. I do not just want to `return arr`, because there are multiple huge objects that are simultaneously manipulated in there. So, I am little unsure on how to achieve it. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: @Sriram is that about a dynamic array or not? We need more clarification please. there are multiple known approaches for typicall cases.

Comment: This is about a dynamic array (I suppose). I do not know `n` before I actually call  the function `init_array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `arr` is being passed by value, so assigning to it in the `init_array()` function doesn't update the variable in `main()`. You need to make it a reference parameter:

```
int init_array(int* &arr)
```

Comment: what about delete[]. do you wanna leave it leakin memory? where did the return statement go?

Comment: @Red.Wave The caller takes responsibility for deleting the object when it's done with it. The rest of the function doesn't change, so I didn't show it.

Comment: but IMHO the OP needs to learn it; I strongly guess he doesn't know.

Comment: Maybe, but that's independent of how he passes the variables around when creating the object.

Comment: I did use what @Barmar suggested. And I deleted the object after calling it. Let me share the actual code where I am using it, if that could help. (https://github.com/ssriram1992/BalasUnionOfPolyhedra/blob/master/BalasPolyhedron.cpp Calling in line 75 and deleting between line 95 and 100)